# URL Rewriting to add / before every path in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, routes, url-routing

I am using Routing in **ASP.Net 4.0.**

**Use of Routing and the side effects**
I did routing of two pages, one page has url profile.aspx?id=yJkl, i converted it into /profile/yJkl. But my paths of CSS, Images and JS got disturbed. I took help from a lot of sites and links and found ignore method, but it did not work.

**I want to use URL Rewriting**
Whenever i add / before any image source or javascript path, it starts working because it takes path from root, i know this. What i want is URL Rewrite, i want that all links of js, aspx, css, images, which were used in my aspx html pages should have a / as prefix in their path. Forexample if i have `<img src='images/blabla.png' />`, asp.net should auto convert it into `<img src='/images/blabla.png'>`.

Please tell me what to add in web.config or tell me if you have any solid solution of routing to ignore. I am newbie in routing/rewriting so forgive me if i asked anything stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ResolveUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) or [ResolveClientUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx)

```
ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/Test.jpg"); //yields "../Images/Test.jpg"

Page.ResolveUrl("~/Images/Test.jpg"); //yields "/Images/Test.jpg"
```